# Having trouble with 74HC595 and Uno

Tags: arduino-uno, code-review, shift-register

Just picked up a couple of 74HC595 shift registers to use for my Arduino Uno, and I'm having trouble getting it working 100% of the time. My code is to get a value from the Serial monitor and shift it into the register. The issue is that bits 4 and 5 are always on no matter what I put into the monitor, but when I clock a 0 into the register during setup(), it works as expected, i.e. all LEDs go off

Here is the code:

```
int dataPin = 2;
int latchPin = 3;
int clockPin = 4;


void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(dataPin, OUTPUT);      
    pinMode(latchPin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(clockPin, OUTPUT);

    digitalWrite(latchPin, LOW);
    shiftOut(dataPin, clockPin, MSBFIRST, 0);
    digitalWrite(latchPin, HIGH);
}

void loop() {
    if(Serial.available()) {
        digitalWrite(latchPin, LOW);
        shiftOut(dataPin, clockPin, MSBFIRST, Serial.read());
        digitalWrite(latchPin, HIGH);
    }
}
```

Is it the code that is wrong? Do i have a busted shift register? Or something else?
Thanks

Comment: You may have incorrect wiring. Maybe you should show it?

Comment: I would be interested if you changed your code to always set bits 4 & 5 to 0. That is, perform the serial read first, bitwise AND the result with 0xFFE7 and then shift out the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Serial.read()` is going to give you ASCII codes.  So when you send 1 from the serial monitor the Arduino receives 49.  Note that the ASCII code for a digit is the same as the digit plus 48, so that sets bits 4 and 5 high.

You can use `Serial.read() - '0'` to get the actual number from the ascii code.